# Flask url parameter capture

Tags: python, flask

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "You need to login"

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    query = flask.request.query_string   # query is printed in terminal
    login = flask.request.get('login')   # here getting AttributeError
    print query, login
    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        return "User is {}, Password is {}".format(flask.request.form['login'],flask.request.form['password']) 
    else:
        return flask.render_template("login.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

When I pass the url in browser `http://127.0.0.1:5000/login?login=hello&password=1234`, it says:

```
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: [Docs suggest](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#accessing-request-data) you need to use `request.args.get('login')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is correct, the Flask [`request` object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#incoming-request-data) has no such method.

Perhaps you wanted to use that on the [`request.args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.args) or [`request.values`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.values) `MultiDict` object instead? `MultiDict` objects *do* have a [`.get()` method](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.get):

```
login = flask.request.args.get('login')
```

Comment: Will accecp ur ans soon, its telling 6 min to wait, till then +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all values in the MultiDict with the same key, then you should use `list_of_values = flask.request.args.getlist('name_of_key')`.